# How to Put image in generated pdf using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to generate the pdf in Codeigniter.I created it successfully but i am not able to put the image in that created pdf using codeigniter.Can you please help me to do this.

I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: In the HTML for the PDF view, are you using absolute paths?

Comment: It is not showing any image in pdf.Can you tell me how i put image in created pdf.yes,i am using absolute path

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the document root to you image path.

E.g.

```
$image = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT").'/image_folder/my_image.png';
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="My image" />
```

If the view is used for both html output and pdf then pass it a variable you can test, and add this if statement to your view;

```
if ($type == 'html')
{
    $root = $this->config->item('base_url');
}
else
{
    $root = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT").'/';
}
```

Then the PHP would be;

```
echo '<img src="'.$root.'image_folder/my_image.png" alt="My image" />';
```